# Parse only top 3 hits from BLAST output with NCBIXML

Tags: python, xml-parsing, biopython, blast

I modified a piece of code as below to parse desired information from BLAST XML output.

```
import csv
from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(open('PGblast.xml', 'rU'))

output = csv.writer(open('PGhit.csv','w'), delimiter =',',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
output.writerow(["Query","Hit ID", "Hit Def", "E-Value"])

E_VALUE_THRESH = 0.00000000000000001

for blast_record in blast_records:
    for alignment in blast_record.alignments:
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
            if hsp.expect < E_VALUE_THRESH:
                output.writerow([blast_record.query[:8],
                                 alignment.hit_id, alignment.hit_def,hsp.expect])

blast_records.close()
```

The code allowed me parse the hits with E-value cut off. But, I wish to parse let's say only the best hit or top 3 hits from BLAST XML output as the BLAST output file is big in size.

Having every hit result parsed will take a lot of time to process and I don't want all hit results in fact.

Could someone kindly please help me?

Comment: I don't get it, you want top 3 by e-value, but don't want to parse the whole file?

Comment: Maybe I was not clear in my question, I'm sorry. I wish to parse the best hit or the best 3 hits of every query in BLAST output file.

Comment: What I don't get is you can filter the entries based on their content without parsing every record in some way.

Comment: @LevLevitsky, I think KJ Lim wants the top 3 alignments for each blast_record. So you would have to decide on metric for how to weigh the HSPs for all alignments, sort and select top 3...

Comment: @deinonychusaur you are right. I want the the top 3 hits alignments (0,1,2) of each blast_record or in other words slices the first three hits. I have 77k+ blast_record to parse, every blast_record has 10 hits result. Thus, I do want top 3 hits from each blast_record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing only the top 3 HSP of each Hit, without parsing the whole file, would require you to write your own custom XML parser. Biopython's NCBIXML does not do this.

However, if it's speed improvement you're looking for, you could try the new SearchIO submodule (http://biopython.org/wiki/SearchIO). It has a new BLAST XML parser that's supposed to be faster than the old NCBIXML parser. The old parser relies on a pure-Python XML parser, while the new one in SearchIO uses `cElementTree` whenever possible.

The submodule is still new and experimental, so there might still be some changes before it hits an official release. If you're interested, there's also a draft tutorial here: http://bow.web.id/biopython/Tutorial.html#htoc96.

Comment: Thanks, Bow. Thanks for your hat tip. 
I did a quick read on the tutorial, something like "slices the first three hits" is the one I tried to ask for guide or suggestion here. I will read that section thoroughly.

Comment: You're welcome. Note that even in the 'slices the first three hits' example, the SearchIO parser will have already parse the entire file as well. If you end up with any problems, head over to the Biopython mailing list (http://biopython.org/wiki/Mailing_lists) with your question :).